# Accessing a MySql datavbase in Xampp

Tags: mysql, xaml

I have installed Xampp for windows version 1.8.2. It is set to listen on port 8080 and seems to be working fine.

I have created a test mysql database with a few tables via the phpmyadmin utility and that looks ok too.

However, I am having problemsd trying to access the db with the following php code:

```
>// Connect to database
>$server = 'localhost';
>$dbname = 'test';
>$user = 'test';
>//$pass = '';
>$con = mysql_connect($server, $dbname, $user) or die("Can't connect to database");
>mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

I am using Dreamweaver and I have set the test server to Local/Network, selected the correct folder where the php test file is located, set the server model to PHP MYSQl and then tried various configurations for the web url including localhost:8080 and various other with differing paths to, for example, the htdocs folder and the MYSQl bin directory. No matter what I do I just keep getting either the Xampp welcome page or else an object not found 404 error.

Any help would be gratefully received - I'm guessing that I'm missing something obvious somewhere but can't see what??

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/phphmyadmin` works ? If yes something with the settings is incorecct could you post your mysql settings ?

I had once the problem that some settings there wrong I changed:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']='mysqli';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']='mysql';
```

in

```
config.inc.php
```

It could also be that the user test just dont exists or he hasnt the rights for it.